# How to undo and redo event in Javascript with browser compatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a tshirt custom design software tool and have to add the redo and undo event for text which is draggable

http://wordpress.tshirtecommerce.com/design-online/?product_id=17

I have tried with undo manager plugin http://mattjmattj.github.io/simple-undo/

Comment: Doing an Undo / Redu system in javascript is pretty easy, because of function closures, all you would need is an array to store you undo-redo stack, and then push your do's and undo's into the array.  eg.  undoredu.push({do:somedofunc(), undo:somundofunc()});  I recently used this technique to do an edit animation here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885261/javascript-settimeout-closure-inside-nested-double-for-loops/39885404#39885404  If you have a look at that, any confusion let us know.

Comment: could you show me how to do it

Comment: I'll see if I can knock up a simple example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are..

This is a simple example of doing an Undo & Redo buffer, and using a function closure to handle the redo..

This is of course a very simple example, so that it is hopefully easy too follow, but there is no reason this technique can't be used to undo/redo anything.  Anything, you pass to a function closure can be captured, and then made to play back.

```js
var e = {}; //lets store references to the dom elemements
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id]")).
  forEach(function (el) { e[el.id] = el; });

var stack = [],
    stackPos = 0,
    names = [];

function showNames() {
  e.lbNames.textContent = names.join(', ');
  e.btUndo.disabled =  stackPos <= 0;
  e.btRedo.disabled = stackPos >= stack.length;
  e.lbBuffer.textContent = stack.length;
}

btAdd.onclick = function () {
  if (!ipName.value) return alert("Please enter some text");
  //a function closure to capture the name
  function add(name) {
    return function () {
      e.ipName.value = '';
      e.ipName.focus();
      names.push(name);
      stackPos ++;
      showNames();
    }
  }
  //no need for closure here, as were just going to pop the
  //last one of the names, and shift the undo-pos back
  function undo() {
    stackPos --;
    names.pop(); 
    showNames();
  }
  //now lets add our do & undo proc
  var doadd = add(ipName.value);
  stack.splice(stackPos);
  stack.push({
    do: doadd,
    undo: undo
  });
  //lets now do our inital do
  doadd();
};

btUndo.onclick = function () {
  var p = stack[stackPos - 1];
  p.undo();
};

btRedo.onclick = function () {
  var p = stack[stackPos];
  p.do();
};

showNames();
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  name: <input id="ipName">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" id="btAdd" >Add</button>
  <button id="btUndo">Undo</button>
  <button id="btRedo">Redo</button>
  Buffer = <span id="lbBuffer"></span>
  <pre id="lbNames"></pre>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, one thing that was niggling me about my original post, is that of re-usability.  The Undo/Redo was also tied too tightly into implementation details.

So I've created a re-usable class version, and at the same time added a clear option too.

I think it's handy keeping the original, and this one for comparison.  So that people can look at the code, and compare.

```js
var e = {}; //lets store references to the dom elemements
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id]")).
  forEach(function (el) { e[el.id] = el; });


function UndoRedo(update_callback, clear_callback) {
  this.update_callback = update_callback;
  this.clear_callback = clear_callback;
  this.clear();
}

UndoRedo.prototype = {
  
  clear: function () {
    this.stack = [];
    this.stackPos = 0;  
    if (this.clear_callback) this.clear_callback();
    this.update();
  },
  
  update: function () {
    if (this.update_callback) this.update_callback();
  },
  
  canUndo: function () { 
    return this.stackPos > 0; 
  },

  canRedo: function () {
    return this.stackPos < this.stack.length;
  },

  doAction: function (doProc, undoProc) {
    this.stack.splice(this.stackPos);
    this.stack.push({
      do: doProc,
      undo: undoProc
    });
    this.stackPos ++;
    doProc(); 
    this.update();
  },
  
  undo: function () {
    var p = this.stack[this.stackPos - 1];
    this.stackPos --;
    p.undo();
    this.update();
  },
  
  redo: function () {
    var p = this.stack[this.stackPos];
    this.stackPos ++;
    p.do();    
    this.update();
  }
  
};  



var     
    names = [],
    undoRedo = new UndoRedo(
      function update() {
        e.lbNames.textContent = names.join(', ');
        e.btUndo.disabled = !this.canUndo();
        e.btRedo.disabled = !this.canRedo();
        e.lbBuffer.textContent = this.stack.length;
      },
      function cleared() {
        names = [];
      }
    );

btAdd.onclick = function () {
  if (!ipName.value) return alert("Please enter some text");
  
  undoRedo.doAction(
    
    function add(name) {
      return function () {
        e.ipName.value = '';
        e.ipName.focus();
        names.push(name);
      }
    }(ipName.value), 
    
    function undo() {
      names.pop(); 
    }
    
  );  
};

btUndo.onclick = function () {
  undoRedo.undo();
};

btRedo.onclick = function () {
  undoRedo.redo();
};

btClear.onclick = function () {
  undoRedo.clear();
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  name: <input id="ipName">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" id="btAdd" >Add</button>
  <button id="btUndo">Undo</button>
  <button id="btRedo">Redo</button>
  Buffer = <span id="lbBuffer"></span>
  <button id="btClear">Clear</button>
  <pre id="lbNames"></pre>
</form>
```