# Element names as constants jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side

Just wondering if anyone has any best practices for naming of jquery elements used in events. e.g elements as constant variables declared at the top, vs inline.

My question for this, is I have a very Jquery heavy client side application and only using server side for data handling and auth.

With this, seeing lines like below drives me a little mad:

```
$("#examplea").hide();
$("#exampleb").fadeIn(300);
```

Does anyone use any separation such as:

```
var examplea = "#examplea";
var exampleb = "#exampleb";

$(examplea).hide();
$(exampleb).fadeIn(300);
```

I see this looking cleaner in some way, and also means having one place to change code if an element name changed down the track and was used in multiple locations.

I guess this only would become an issue for very large javascript heavy sites, so just throwing out the question on what other people have done to deal with this?

Thanks,

Comment: `var $exampleA = $('#exampleA'); $exampleA.hide();` is my preferred method, and I believe most common practice. The `$` in the variable name isn't completely necessary but is a nice notation to indicate that the variable is a JQuery Object.

Comment: @Santi's solution is definitely better. DOM queries are expensive and you should try to do as few as possible

Comment: @Jorg Not an issue!

Comment: read some style guides... conventions vary across projects but you can get some ideas from them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going to the DOM to fetch the same elements is relatively slow, especially if you get those elements often. It might be better to store the actual jQ variable of it:

```
var $examplea = $('#examplea');
```

so that you can use it everywhere else:

```
$examplea.hide();
$examplea.fadeIn(300);
```

Comment: I'm amazed after all these years of using Jquery ive never considered the cost in fetching from the DOM, always been too worried about the performance in my data fetching. Need to go beat myself with a stick for a while. Great answer. 
Prefixing the $ as per @Santi's comment is also a nice notation to add.

Comment: @Nick noted and changed. Try it in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/zk7egghv/), you'll be surprised.

Comment: that jsfiddle shocked me. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I often place such things inside a simple object literal, and in some cases auto fill this object literal.

eg.  recently knocked up a simple example of an undo / redo.. It's not jQuery but pure javascript.  And right at the top I pull the names of elements automatically from the DOM. For me I think it keeps things a little bit more DRY.

[How to undo and redo event in Javascript with browser compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894830/how-to-undo-and-redo-event-in-javascript-with-browser-compatible?noredirect=1#comment67078772_39894830)

If you look at the first few lines, you will see how I'm capturing all the elements and placing into an object literal 'e';