# How to undo and redo onclick in svg element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have svg text fill which is dynamic. once the user click undo button it must undo the svg and textarea and once the user click redo button it should redo the svg text fill and textarea. i have completed with the textarea undo and redo functionality but not with svg element how to achieve this through jquery

```
   $("#enter-text").on("keypress",function(){
 $("#svg_id").html($(this).val());
  })

//this value is kept small for testing purposes, you'd probably want to    use sth. between 50 and 200
const stackSize = 10;

  //left and right define the first and last "index" you can actually       navigate to, a frame with maximum stackSize-1 items between them.
  //These values are continually growing as you push new states to the    stack, so that the index has to be clamped to the actual index in stack by      %stackSize.
   var stack = Array(stackSize), left=0, right=0, index = 0, timeout;
 //push the first state to the stack, usually an empty string, but not    necessarily
 stack[0] = $("#enter-text").val();
updateButtons();

$("#enter-text").on("keydown keyup change", detachedUpdateText);
$("#undo").on("click", undo);
$("#redo").on("click", redo);

//detach update
function detachedUpdateText(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(updateText, 500);
}

   function updateButtons(){
    //disable buttons if the index reaches the respective border of the        frame
    //write the amount of steps availabe in each direction into the data-    count attribute, to be processed by css
       $("#undo")
        .prop("disabled", index === left)
        .attr("data-count", index-left);

       $("#redo")
        .prop("disabled", index === right)
          .attr("data-count", right-index);

    //show status
       $("#stat").html(JSON.stringify({
        left,
        right,
        index,
        "index in stack": index % stackSize,
        stack
    }, null, 4))
}

function updateText(){
    var val = $("#enter-text").val().trimRight();
    //skip if nothing really changed
    if(val === stack[index % stackSize]) return;

    //add value
    stack[++index % stackSize] = val;

    //clean the undo-part of the stack
    while(right > index)
        stack[right-- % stackSize] = null;

    //update boundaries
    right = index;
    left = Math.max(left, right+1-stackSize);

    updateButtons();
}

function undo(){
    if(index > left){
        $("#enter-text").val(stack[--index % stackSize]);
        updateButtons();
    }
    }

     function redo(){
    if(index < right){
        $("#enter-text").val(stack[++index % stackSize]);
        updateButtons();
    }
     }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yvp3jedr/6/

Comment: Not sure if you noticed on my last reply to you about undo/redo.  The second answer I created a Class version that de-coupled the undo-redo logic to make this a bit easier.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894830/how-to-undo-and-redo-event-in-javascript-with-browser-compatible/39897359#39897359  The only things you really need to know about undo/redo, is 2 things, what did I do to "do", and what would I need to do to "undo"  (IOW: reverse what I've just done).  Also what is it with the SVG your wanting to do, because currently your just copying text from the input into the SVG.

Comment: @keith my undo redo functionality works fine but right now textarea value will filled dynamically in svg element. so undo should be done for svg also. it is a tshirt custom product design.

Comment: So I'm assuming you have an SVG that your updating, currently your code is just replacing everything in the SVG with what's in the TextArea.

Comment: I'm assuming you have an SVG of a tshirt, that then you want users to be able to modify??,  If so then maybe I could later have a go at modifying my last example to show this..

Comment: @keith yes you are right. http://wordpress.tshirtecommerce.com/ click tshirt

Comment: That link seems to be blocked for me.. Just returns "Not Acceptable!"

Comment: Refresh the link again or else use another browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125394/discussion-between-parker-and-keith).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#enter-text").on("keypress", function () {
    $("#svg_id").text($(this).val());
})

//this value is kept small for testing purposes, you'd probably want to use sth. between 50 and 200
const stackSize = 10;

//left and right define the first and last "index" you can actually navigate to, a frame with maximum stackSize-1 items between them.
//These values are continually growing as you push new states to the stack, so that the index has to be clamped to the actual index in stack by %stackSize.
var stack = Array(stackSize), left = 0, right = 0, index = 0, timeout;
//push the first state to the stack, usually an empty string, but not necessarily
stack[0] = $("#enter-text").val();
updateButtons();

$("#enter-text").on("keydown keyup change", detachedUpdateText);
$("#undo").on("click", undo);
$("#redo").on("click", redo);

//detach update
function detachedUpdateText() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(updateText, 500);
}

function updateButtons() {
    //disable buttons if the index reaches the respective border of the frame
    //write the amount of steps availabe in each direction into the data-count attribute, to be processed by css
    $("#undo")
        .prop("disabled", index === left)
        .attr("data-count", index - left);

    $("#redo")
        .prop("disabled", index === right)
        .attr("data-count", right - index);

    //show status
    $("#stat").html(JSON.stringify({
        left,
        right,
        index,
        "index in stack": index % stackSize,
        stack
    }, null, 4))
}

function updateText() {
    var val = $("#enter-text").val().trimRight();
    //skip if nothing really changed
    if (val === stack[index % stackSize]) return;

    //add value
    stack[++index % stackSize] = val;

    //clean the undo-part of the stack
    while (right > index)
        stack[right-- % stackSize] = null;

    //update boundaries
    right = index;
    left = Math.max(left, right + 1 - stackSize);

    updateButtons();
}

function undo() {
    if (index > left) {
        var text = stack[--index % stackSize];
        $("#enter-text").val(text);
        $("#svg_id").text(text);
        updateButtons();
    }
}

function redo() {
    if (index < right) {
        var text = stack[++index % stackSize];
        $("#enter-text").val(text);
        $("#svg_id").text(text);
        updateButtons();
    }
}
```

Comment: svg will be dynamic text fill